# Is there a limitation on running db query in imported function in django tests?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tests

I am using function in views  to query db (postgresql), calculate values and return list of lists. When I call it from views.py I get what is expected. When I call it from test.py I get empty list (not error, not None). To investigate I have created list of lists in views function manually and it was returned just fine (so there is no issue with import or length of returned value). It seems that if I call function imported from views that makes a db query and it is called from TestCase object then the db query is not done. Why?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from <my app>.views import calc
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

class CalcTestCase(TestCase):
    maxDiff = None
    def test_calc_image(self):
        start_time = datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('UTC') )
        finish_time = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('UTC') )
        instance_type = "test"
        output = calc(instance_type, start_time, finish_time)
        test_output = [[test, values, in],[list, of, lists]]
        self.assertEqual(output, test_output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the tests always run from an empty database. You need to create entries for your tests within the test cases themselves. See [the testing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database).